# Excel Grid Lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an array in one file, for example:

```
    Names    Age   Shoe Size
    Andrew   19    12
    Mary     17     8
    Sarah    15    10
    Wesley   19    11
```

I want to pinpoint one piece of data based on a given name and data type.
For example, pinpoint `Sarah` and `Age`, I want the cell to read `15`.

I have read [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TablesAndLookups.aspx) helpful guide on Double Lookups, but one thing is still bothering me.

Here is the formula:

`=OFFSET(A1:C5,MATCH("Sarah",OFFSET(A1:C5,0,0,ROWS(A1:C5),1),0)-1,MATCH("Age",OFFSET(A1:C5,0,0,1,COLUMNS(A1:C5)),0)-1)`

It works when the data is in the same file, however when I try and use the given formula from another file, it gets a `#VALUE!` error.

Code for reading from anther file (all I did was add the file path):

```
=OFFSET(C:file\path\'[Lister.xls]Shhet1'!$A$1:$C$5,MATCH("Sarah",OFFSET(C:file\path\'[Lister.xls]Shhet1'!$A$1:$C$5,0,0,ROWS(C:file\path\'[Lister.xls]Shhet1'!$A$1:$C$5),1),0)-1,MATCH("Age",OFFSET(C:file\path\'[Lister.xls]Shhet1'!$A$1:$C$5,0,0,1,COLUMNS(C:file\path\'[Lister.xls]Shhet1'!$A$1:$C$5)),0)-1)
```

Here it is spaced so it is easier to read:

```
=OFFSET(C:file\path\'[Lister.xls]Shhet1'!$A$1:$C$5,
MATCH("Sarah", OFFSET(C:file\path\'[Lister.xls]Shhet1'!$A$1:$C$5, 0, 0,
ROWS(C:file\path\'[Lister.xls]Shhet1'!$A$1:$C$5),1), 0)-1,
MATCH("Age", OFFSET(C:file\path\'[Lister.xls]Shhet1'!$A$1:$C$5, 0, 0, 1, 
COLUMNS(C:file\path\'[Lister.xls]Shhet1'!$A$1:$C$5)), 0)-1)
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't like other files?
It's the same information.

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to expand on Scott's answer, external paths to closed workbooks are treated like arrays not references so functions that are expecting references in arguments like OFFSET, SUMIF, or COUNTIF return errors if the workbook is closed.

INDEX on the other hand does allow arrays as arguments, so you could try entering instead:

```
=INDEX(A1:C5,MATCH("Sarah",INDEX(A1:C5,0,1),0),MATCH("Age",INDEX(A1:C5,1,0),0))
```

which should allow for references to closed workbooks as well.

A further advantage of INDEX is that it is not volatile so will only recalculate when a cell in one of the dependent cells (A1:C5) changes whereas OFFSET is a volatile function and will recalculate whenever a change is made anywhere in the workbook which is less efficient.

Comment: Saved me the trouble of looking into `Index` myself! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Some functions require that the target workbook is open to work - Offset is one of these. Indirect and Sumif and Countif are others. You will have to have the target open, or redesign the process.

You can try using the index function since it is similar to the offset function.

Comment: Yep that seems to be the problem, I'll look into `Index`, thanks!